# How to capture DVB-T using a generic RTL2832U USB stick on a mac

Tags: mac, osx, vlc

Is there a way to capture DVB-T video using a [generic USB DVB-T dongle](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B009VBUYA0) on a mac?  I've read many [examples of people using VLC](http://www.izitips.com/software/how-to-watch-dvb-t-with-vlc-media-player/) on Linux/PCs, but can't see any generic drivers on Mac OSX?

Comment: So, why not use VLC on Mac? Or what problems with that you are facing?

Comment: VLC on OSX doesn't decode from the DVB stick.

Comment: There are no drivers, but if you can configure it manually, I'm guessing you'd be able to create a fifo or tcp socket for vlc to read from as mpeg2? Have librtlsdr installed through brew.

Answer (score 1):

Seems unlikely as per this [section](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/MacPorts#Capture_Cards_and_Video_Sources) on the MythTV wiki:

> Pretty much the only Capture Cards that are supported on OS X are the
>   HDHomerun tuners from Silicondust

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no direct way to do it on mac but it works on linux so you can do it on a virtual machine. Just install VirtualBox, then install xubuntu on VirtualBox, and on xubuntu install Kaffeine which allows to play and record DVB-T streams. I used it like that with a RTL2832U DVB-T dongle and it worked fine. Just make sure that you set USB 3.0 in virtual machine settings and allow using all cpu cores because without that it will be too slow and won't work.